# Window suspends while testing MySQL Connection

Tags: c#, mysql

I am writing software which works with a MySQL Database using MySql.Data.MysqlClient (for the connection) and Windows Form (to depict the DB).

This is my first software and I want to improve so I have some questions.
The following Code tests the connection to the MySQL Server by opening the Connection and pinging.

```
 public bool test_connection(Config c)
    {
        bool test = false;
        string test_connection_key = build_path(c.k.server_ip, c.k.user, c.k.user_password, "information_schema");            
        using(MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(test_connection_key))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                test = connection.Ping();
                connection.Close();


            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                Protokoll.save_string("MySQL ERROR: " + ex.Number.ToString());
            }
            return test;
        }
```

While `connection.Open()` is running I **am unable to move the window**(GUI).

I want to make the user able to click on Buttons (which have nothing to do with the MySQL connection but the **window freezes**.

After the program tried to open a connection (no matter if succeed or not)
I can move the window again.

Comment: Do it asynchronously. Right now you're opening the connection on the GUI's thread, which will block it until the connection is opened (or fails to open).

Comment: You have any keywords for me? Never did anything asynchronously ;)

Comment: Look up "c# threads" or, if you want to, look up "async and await in c#". Threads are easier to use though.